iOS tapping/swiping back with navigationBar's leftBarButtonItem as systemIcon sometimes makes the button look pushed down/greyed out
I was towards the end of writing a whole SO post when I actually stumbled upon the source of the issue.

The issue was that sometimes when I tapped the back button (or swipe
back) on a specific ViewController (let's call it VC-B), its parent
(call it VC-A) came back into view with its leftBarButtonItem
greyed out (ie. being pushed down), and it stayed that way until I
pushed down on it or tapped it (meaning the button might even have
look disabled but it was not, because I could use it to segue back to
the VC-B). Note that from other buttons in VC-A I could trigger
multiple VCs to be popped onto the navigation stack, but when I
ultimately popped back to root, VC-A would still have the
leftBarButtonItem with the greyed out look. Using Debug Hierarchy View I could tell that the button's image alpha was stuck at 0.2.

By trial and error I ultimately discovered that this was happening when the leftBarButtonItem used a systemIcon for its image. Swapping it out with a custom UIImage fixed the issue.
Any ideas of what could be causing this? Or a way around it (I'd still like to use the system image)?
